# How do I get the description from a woocommerce product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im building a short code to display product info when passed with an ID, Ive got the title and image working but the description is the one Im having trouble with.

```
function wcproductslider($atts) {
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'product' => '98',
), $atts );

$product_ID = $a['product'];
$pro = new WC_Product($product_ID);

$ret = "<b>Title: </b>".$pro->get_title() . "<br>";

$ret .= "<b>Image: </b><br> <a href=' " .$pro->get_permalink() . " '>".$pro->get_image($size = 'shop_thumbnail') . "</a><br>"; 

$ret .= "<b>Long Description: </b>" . $pro->post->post_content;
$ret .= "<b>Short description: </b>" . $pro->post->post_excerpt;
return $ret;

}
```

I managed to figure some of it out using [wc product class](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) but theres nothing about the product excerpt.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think all of the post data is stored in `$pro->post`, so you may be able to use `$pro->post->post_excerpt`

Comment: tried it no joy :/ even with brackets but that gave me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, didn't put anything in my short description of the product.

Long Description

```
$pro->post->post_content;
```

Short Description

```
$pro->post->post_excerpt;
```

Comment: I would suggest using the following `apply_filters('the_content', $pro->post->post_content);` This will run any shortcodes you had in the content, auto-embed any videos, apply paragraph tags if `wpautop` is enabled. It will essentially do all of the stuff you would expect from `the_content()`

Comment: See that 2 interesting threads: [how to display product description of woo…](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25474810/3730754) and [Woocommerce Get Product Values by ID](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35165541/3730754)

Comment: Running the `the_content` filter *might* also get you in trouble if you are using any plugins that hook into that. For example, I once had sharing icons all over my site. For the short content, WooCommerce has a `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt()` function that runs the excerpt through it's own `woocommerce_short_description` filter which presumably mimics most of the filters run on `the_content` without opening yourself up to social icon insanity.